# Widget isn't a type

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

When I Create a new Widget then uper widget shows error.

> Widget isn't a type.

[image: here is Screen shot of my code screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in flutter is a widget and if you want to create your own widget to reuse it, you can do it this way:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 56.0,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue[500]),
      child: Card(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And after creating you reusable widget you can import it to where you want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is with your function that you named Widget... change its name

Comment: it helped, please  mark it as an answer